# Parse xml for getting data

Tags: xml

I need to parse this xml and get last-name by Id(99999) or by Id(55555) based on what I set in method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmldata
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS">
    <recordset name="object" nritems="1" acl="AW">
        <record name="object" id="99999" acl="DW">
            <field name="last-name" acl="TW">**SS**</field>
        </record>
    </recordset>
</xmldata>
```

I am trying this for Id

```
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(responseBody);
String subjectID = document.getRootElement()
            .getChildElement('recordset', null)
            .getChildElement('recordname', null).getText();
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this.

```
DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
document.load(responseBody);
String subjectID = document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElement('record', null).getAttribute('id', '');
String name;
for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
        .getChildElement('recordset', null)
        .getChildElement('record', null).getChildElements()) {
    if (xmlNode.getAttribute('name', '') == 'name') {
        name = xmlNode.getText();
    }
}
System.debug(
        subjectID
);
System.debug(name);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to eplain what the difference is and why this code works (but the code OP is using didn't)

Comment: Yes it works perfect!